# Lstlisting delimiters remove indentation

Tags: listings, indentation, delimiters

I am trying to change color of text in the listing. I use delimiters, but it seems that they remove indentation.

Here is my setup:

```
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{javared}{rgb}{0.6,0,0} % for strings
\definecolor{javagreen}{rgb}{0.25,0.5,0.35} % comments
\definecolor{javapurple}{rgb}{0.5,0,0.35} % keywords
\definecolor{javadocblue}{rgb}{0.25,0.35,0.75} % javadoc

\lstset{language=Java,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    frame=single,
    breaklines=true,
    columns=fullflexible,
    keywordstyle=\color{javapurple}\bfseries,
    stringstyle=\color{javared},
    commentstyle=\color{javagreen},
    morecomment=[s][\color{javadocblue}]{/**}{*/},
    tabsize=4,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    escapeinside={(*@}{@*)},
    moredelim=[il][\textcolor{pyellow}]{$$},
    moredelim=[is][\textcolor{pgrey}]{\%\%}{\%\%},
    moredelim=[is][\color{red}]{|}{|},
    moredelim=[is][\color{green}]{#}{#}
}

\begin{lstlisting}
|+      THIS SHOULD BE GREEN|
#-      THIS SHOULD BE RED#
\end{lstlisting}
```

This is output with missing indentation:

[image: Missing identation]

Are my settings correct? Is there any way to keep indentation or insert it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beside the spacing problem, note that the `#` character in LaTeX has a special meaning and so needs to be escaped when used as a delimiter for listings. Your last delimiter definition should thus read

```
moredelim=[is][\color{green}]{\#}{\#}
```

---

The missing spaces occur because you are using the option `columns=fullflexible`. For column alignment, `listings` has four options, namely `fixed`, `flexible`, `spaceflexible` and `fullflexible`. The differences between them are described in section 2.10 of the [`listings` manual](https://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf).

For longer, monospaced listings you probably want to use the `fixed` or `flexible` format. The effects of the four options on your example can be seen in the following image:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, now it works as expected.